# How do I run Ansible tests related to a specific module?

Tags: ansible

I tried to read https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/ but I couldn't find any instructions about how to run all tests related to a specific ansible module.

As an occasional contributor I do want to locally run tests around the module I am trying to patch. Running the entire test suite for such a big project is extremely hard.

For example lets say I touched a `lib/ansible/modules/cloud/docker/docker_image.py` file, what do I need to run in order to test my change, before pushing it and creating a PR to test it on CI.

Comment: The doc about creating modules has a [section about adding your own unit tests and running them](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html#unit-tests). The given example command can probably apply to existing modules and tests. Not sure it really/fully answers your question though.